# redirect *.exapmle.com/foo/bar?moo=soo to exapmle.net/foo/bar?moo=soo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i want redirect all request to

```
*.exapmle.com/foo/bar?moo=soo TO exapmle.net/foo/bar?moo=soo
```

for example

```
www.exapmle.com/foo/bar?moo=soo TO exapmle.net/foo/bar?moo=soo
```

or

```
exapmle.com/foo/bar?moo=soo TO exapmle.net/foo/bar?moo=soo
```

how do it with htaceess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i redirect [wildcard].exapmle.com/[wildcard2] to example.net/[wildcard2] for example s1.example.com/content/1?from=test to example.net/content/1?from=test

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your exapmle.com site

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  exapmle\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^  http://exapmle.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. how i redirect [wildcard].exapmle.com/[wildcard2] to example.net/[wildcard2] for example s1.example.com/content/1?from=test to example.net/content/1?from=test .

Comment: @arastu see the changes above for your request